# Event Fees - DB Error: syntax error

Tags: wordpress, civievent

after upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.23 for Wordpress I can no longer configure Event Fees and get a DB Error: syntax error.

I tried upgrading to 4.7.24 and still no joy.

The log file contains this:

```
    Sep 28 12:41:10  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT  id, entity_id  
 FROM civicrm_entity_financial_account 

 WHERE ( account_relationship =  AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id  
 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id' at line 4]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT  id, entity_id  
 FROM civicrm_entity_financial_account 

 WHERE ( account_relationship =  AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id  
 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id' at line 4]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT  id, entity_id  
 FROM civicrm_entity_financial_account 

 WHERE ( account_relationship =  AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id  
 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type'  )  


 ORDER BY entity_id' at line 4]"]
)
```

I have since found more issues which may be related.

I can no longer edit or add Payment Processors and get an error saying: This financial account cannot have '' relationship.

I also can't add or edit Price Sets.

Further digging found this in my tracestack:

/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/FinancialType.php(196): CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::populate(NULL, "CRM_Financial_DAO_EntityFinancialAccount", TRUE, "entity_id", NULL, "account_relationship =  AND entity_table = 'civicrm_financial_type' ")

Comment: Is it possible you installed an extension that adds a payment processor (e.g. Stripe), created a payment processor, then uninstalled/deleted the extension without deleting the payment processor record?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately this is not the case as I only ever used the built in Paypal payment processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have disabled the CiviContribute Component which lead the function to return NULL for account relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce this [and give us your exact steps] on one of the demo sites (Wordpress or Drupal - http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm - does not really matter) - then this (a Fatal Error) will get prompt attention; There are several code Sprints going on this week - reporting live from Montreal!

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's really useful. I couldn't reproduce the problem. However I have since found another issue which may be related. I can no longer edit or add Payment Processors. If I try I get an error saying: This financial account cannot have '' relationship. I can't try to reproduce this on the demo as I do not have enough permission to make those changes.

Comment: Ah - so that sounds like the underlying issue - perhaps somehow some Financial Accounts got deleted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've compared all of the *financial* tables with a backup of my database and they are exactly the same apart from 2 extra records in the civicdm_finalncial_account table in the newest database. I tried deleting them but made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue when CiviContribute is disabled is with price sets: menu for new price set is active, but throws a DB syntax error when new price set is submitted.

See more here: [CiviMember price sets are depending on CiviContribute?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28371/civimember-price-sets-are-depending-on-civicontribute)

Comment: Thanks Doka - could you expand this to make it clearly an Answer eg "therefore disable Price Sets before disabling CiviContribute"?