# CiviMember price sets are depending on CiviContribute?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, price-sets

When only CiviMember is enabled as active component, setting new price sets (civicrm/admin/price) throws am DB syntax error.

When CiviContribute is also enabled, setting new prices works.

Since these are two distinct components, I consider this as a bug. Please advise.

I'm on the lates CiviCRM version of 5.9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to CiviCRM StackExchange!

Price sets are meant to create/interact with contributions which require CiviContribute to be enabled. Hence it makes sense that they only work if you have CiviContribute enbaled.

However it would make sense to not show any price set options in the UI as long as CiviContribute is enabled. You could create an issue for that on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core

Comment: Thank, the issue is reported here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/702