# "Failed to load resource" error when trying to view fees under manage events

Tags: civievent, drupal

I am trying to add fees to a new event in a fairly new installation of CiviCRM on a Drupal CMS. When I click on the fees tab I get the following error displayed in the browser:

**Network Error**
*Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.*

and this in the console window:

*jquery.js?pxiki7:10255 GET https://[DOMAIN NAME]/civicrm/event/manage/fee?reset=1&action=update&id=2&component=event&snippet=json 500 (Internal Server Error)*

I was also getting a "Failed to load resource" error in the console window too although that seems to have stopped.

also, if I hover over the fees tab is says *fees (disabled)*.

I am fairly new to civiCRM and Drupal so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this behavior persist if you change your browser? What version of CiviCRM are you using? What do you see on https://yoursite.com/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

Comment: I get the same behaviour using IE (was using Chrome).

Comment: ResourceURL: [civicrm.root]/
Image Upload: civicrm.files/]/persist/contribute
custom CSS: Blank
Disable civicrm css: No
extension resource url: [civicrm]/ext/
Force Secure URL: Was NO, changed to yes, same issues
Very SSL Certs: Yes

civicrm 15.14.2

Comment: I have since upgraded to 5.17.0 but still have the same issue.

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/ maybe we could turn on some debugging and find out more about the 500 (Internal Server Error) ?

Comment: Can you check in civicrm log or drupal logs to see any errors?

Comment: When I click the 'Fees' tab I get the **NETWORK ERROR Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.** pop up and then in the console window with debugging turned on I get the error: **jquery.js?pxm6dw:10255 GET https://www.domainname/civicrm/event/manage/fee?reset=1&action=update&id=3&component=event&snippet=json 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: If I try and go to the fees screen from the **manage events** screen I get the following error:
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "DB Error: syntax error"
#0 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(1419): civicrm_api3("Event", "getoptions", (Array:4))
#1 /civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/Fee.php(267): CRM_Core_Form->addSelect("financial_type_id")
#2 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(611): CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee->buildQuickForm()
#3 /civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()

Comment: #4 /civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee), "display")
#5 /civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee), "display")
#6 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#7 /civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(114): CRM_Core_Controller->run()#8 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(263): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Fee", "Event Fees", (Array:0))

Comment: #9 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#10 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#11 /civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#12 /public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", "manage", "fee")
#13 /public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#14 {main}

Comment: Anybody got any ideas on this one? I have tried on another installation and getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came accross this article: [Event Fees - DB Error: syntax error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20647/event-fees-db-error-syntax-error)

It turns out that if you disable the CiviContribute component it causes errors with Event fees!